# Какой алгоритм использует больше памяти?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, profile, profiler

Есть два двумерных массива numpy (заведомо огромных). Необходимо вывести двумерный массив (два столбца и N строк) пар индексов строк, значения в первых 5ти элементов которых совпадают в обоих массивах. Например:

```
array1 = np.array([
    [1, 4, 3, 6, 2, 6, 2, 5],
    [7, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 2],
    [3, 3, 6, 2, 1, 6, 8, 4],
    [1, 6, 3, 8, 6, 8, 4, 2],
])

array2 = np.array([
    [6, 2, 4, 1, 6, 4, 2, 2],
    [1, 4, 3, 6, 2, 6, 2, 5],
    [1, 6, 3, 8, 6, 8, 4, 2],
    [5, 3, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 2],
])

result = np.array([
    [0, 1],
    [3, 2],
])
```

Есть два варианта реализации

1. который жрет много памяти:

```
matches = np.array(np.all((np.round(array1[:,:6], decimals=4)[:, None, :] == np.round(array2[:,:6], decimals=4)[None, :, :]), axis=-1).nonzero()).T
```

2. который долгий:

```
matches = np.array([])
for i in range(array1.shape[0]):
    correspond_map = np.all((np.round(array1[i, :6], decimals=4) == np.round(array2[:,:6], decimals=4)), axis=-1)
    idx = np.where(correspond_map)[0]
    if idx.shape[0] != 0:
        if matches.shape[0] != 0:
            matches = np.vstack((matches, np.array([i, idx[0]])))
        else:
            matches = np.array([i, idx[0]])
```

я хочу получить количественно (чтоб графики построить) сколько памяти потребляет каждый алгоритм, но пока не нашел решения, как именно. Memory profiler дает какую то дичь, либо я не понял как им пользоваться правильно.

Comment: Для вас действительно каждый бит памяти очень важен? У вас, может быть, места нет на компьютере?

Comment: Зачем `np.round` на массиве целых  чисел?

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы померять расход памяти в NumPy инструментально используйте [numpy.ndarray.nbytes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.nbytes.html). Чтобы измерения были честными, нужно измерять потребление памяти для всех временных массивов, которые создаются при вычислении выражений.

Оценим расход памяти "вручную". Поставим эксперимент над массивами из 20 и 30 строчек:

> ```
> @>>> a = np.arange(120).reshape((-1, 6))
> @>>> a.shape
> (20, 6)
> @>>> b = np.arange(180).reshape((-1, 6))
> @>>> b.shape
> (30, 6)
> ```

Преобразуем размерности:

> ```
> @>>> a2 = a[:, None, :]
> @>>> a2.shape
> (20, 1, 6)
> @>>> b2 = b[None, :, :]
> @>>> b2.shape
> (1, 30, 6)
> ```

До сих пор массивы по размеру были пропорциональны исходным. Сейчас всё изменится. Сравниваем:

> ```
> @>>> c = a2 == b2
> @>>> c.shape
> (20, 30, 6)
> ```

Новый массив стал значительно больше. Сворачиваем последнее измерение:

> ```
> @>>> c2 = np.all(c, axis=-1)
> @>>> c2.shape
> (20, 30)
> ```

Строим пары:

> ```
> @>>> c3 = np.array(c2.nonzero()).T
> @>>> c3.shape
> (20, 2)
> ```

В конце массив снова стал небольшим.

Обобщаем:

> ```
> Имя    Размер           Пример
>
> a      N * 6            20 * 6
> b      M * 6            30 * 6
>
> a2     N * 1 * 6        20 * 1 * 6
> b2     1 * M * 6        1 * 30 * 6
>
> c      N * M * 6        20 * 30 * 6
>
> c2     N * M            20 * 30
>
> c3     min(M, N) * 2    20 * 2
> ```

Максимальное потребление памяти составляет *6NM*. В терминах *O*-большого - *O(NM)*. Если простыми словами, алгоритм потребляет квадратичную память. И поэтому работает за квадрат.

Аналогичный анализ для второго алгоритма даст максимальную память в итерации *6M*. Это линейный по памяти алгоритм. К сожалению, из-за ошибки в накоплении результатов (повторяющиеся вызовы `np.vstack`) он тоже будет работать за квадратичное время.

Выводы: первый алгоритм требует квадратичную память, второй - линейную. Оба алгоритма работают за квадратичное время. Первый кажется быстрее, так как у него меньше константа. На больших массивах тормозить будут оба.

**P.S.** Линейный алгоритм с линейной памятью:

```
import numpy as np


array1 = np.array([
    [1, 4, 3, 6, 2, 6, 2, 5],
    [7, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 2],
    [3, 3, 6, 2, 1, 6, 8, 4],
    [1, 6, 3, 8, 6, 8, 4, 2],
])

array2 = np.array([
    [6, 2, 4, 1, 6, 4, 2, 2],
    [1, 4, 3, 6, 2, 6, 2, 5],
    [1, 6, 3, 8, 6, 8, 4, 2],
    [5, 3, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 2],
])


relation = {}
for i, r in enumerate(np.round(array1[:,:6], decimals=4)):
    relation.setdefault(tuple(r), ([], []))[0].append(i)
for i, r in enumerate(np.round(array2[:,:6], decimals=4)):
    relation.setdefault(tuple(r), ([], []))[1].append(i)

result = []
for i1, i2 in relation.values():
    if i1 and i2:
        result.append((i1, i2))
print(result)
```

> ```
> $ python temp.py
> [([0], [1]), ([3], [2])]
> ```